# Reactjs: How to edit table on specific row?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([
    {id: 1, name: 'paper', qty: 10},
    {id: 2, name: 'bottle', qty: 10},
 ]);

 const [isEditable, setEditable] = useState([]);

 useEffect(()=>{
   data.map(each=>{
     isEditable[each.id] = false;
   })
 })
 
  const handleEdit = (id) => {
     var arr = data;
     arr[id] = !arr[id];
     setEditable(arr);
  }
  return (
    <div>
         {data.map((row) => (
          <TableRow key={row.id}>
            <TableCell>{row.id}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
            { isEditable[row.id] ? 
              <TableCell>
                <TextField id="outlined-basic" size="small" variant="outlined" />
              </TableCell> :
              <TableCell>{row.qty}</TableCell> 
            }
            <TableCell>
                <button onClick={()=> handleEdit(row.id)}> Edit </button>
            </TableCell>                                            
          </TableRow>
        ))}

    </div>
  )
}
```

I'd like to click on Edit button on the table row and the Textfield appears only on specific row, but here when I click it, the textfields are appear on other rows instead. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why your code looks complicated that way. Personally I think you can make it simpler as following to reach your goals:

- Just store id which you are editing:

```js
const [editingId, setId] = useState();
```

- Set the editing ID as you click on the edit button:

```js
const handleEdit = (id) => {
  setId(id);
}
```

- Check the condition to show the text input in your JSX:

```js
{editingId === row.id ? 
  <TableCell>
    <TextField id="outlined-basic" size="small" variant="outlined" />
  </TableCell> :
  <TableCell>{row.qty}</TableCell> 
}
```

You might have to handle to update the list in immutable way as you have finished editing as well.